# "Tracking" connections with Thrift

Tags: c++, rpc, thrift

I am trying to create a game using Thrift, so that the clients are the players, and the server manages the boards, much like [this](http://www.facebook.com/careers/puzzles.php?puzzle_id=14). However, I cannot figure out how Facebook's Thrift server can "track" the user, i.e. when calling `attack()` on [their service](http://www.facebook.com/jobs_puzzles/battleship2.thrift), I do not have to identify myself again.

According to what the generated server stub suggests, there is no way to do this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int port = 9090;
  shared_ptr<ConnectFourHandler> handler(new ConnectFourHandler());
  shared_ptr<TProcessor> processor(new ConnectFourProcessor(handler));
  shared_ptr<TServerTransport> serverTransport(new TServerSocket(port));
  shared_ptr<TTransportFactory> transportFactory(new TBufferedTransportFactory());
  shared_ptr<TProtocolFactory> protocolFactory(new TBinaryProtocolFactory());

  TSimpleServer server(processor, serverTransport, transportFactory, protocolFactory);
  server.serve();
  return 0;
}
```

In that example, there is only one handler being created for the server, and the server is what accepts connections.

How is Facebook able to keep track of what clients are connected to the server, if all requests are routed through only one handler per server?

Answer (score 0):

Try `server.setServerEventHandler`.  It'll call your code when a new client connects, giving you the opportunity to create a connection-specific context object.

Comment: `serServerEventHandler` will only you so far ... unless the info is passed to the actual handler (see `attack()` in OP) its not easy if at all possible

Answer (score 0):

Because thrift uses a unique thread for each connection it is possible to use the thread id to link the two together. As far as I know there is no way to do this from thrift itself. Imo it would be possible if thrift passed a context field down to each handler function.

Here is an example that uses the thread id:

```
#include <map>
#include <thread>

typedef struct {
    // you would put your connection specific variables here
} ConnectionContext;

// You could reverse these types if you had more than one
// context per thrift connection, eg. your service involved opening
// or connecting to more than one thing per thrift connection
std::map<std::thread::id, ConnectionContext> threadContextMap;

class OurEventHandler : public server::TServerEventHandler {
public:
OurEventHandler() :
    NumClients_(0)
{}

//Called before the server begins -
//virtual void preServe() {}

//createContext may return a user-defined context to aid in cleaning
//up client connections upon disconnection. This example dispenses
//with contextual information and returns NULL.
virtual void* createContext(shared_ptr<protocol::TProtocol> input, 
shared_ptr<protocol::TProtocol> output)
{
    printf("Client connected (total %d)\n", ++NumClients_);

    auto this_id = std::this_thread::get_id();
    std::cout << "connected thread " << this_id << std::endl;

    return NULL;
}

//Called when an client has disconnected, either naturally or by error.
virtual void deleteContext(void* serverContext, 
shared_ptr<protocol::TProtocol>input, shared_ptr<protocol::TProtocol>output)
{
    printf("Client disconnected (total %d)\n", --NumClients_);

    auto this_id = std::this_thread::get_id();
    std::cout << "disconnected thread " << this_id << std::endl;

    auto context = threadContextMap[this_id];

    // TODO: Perform your context specific cleanup code here
}

protected:
    uint32_t NumClients_;
};


class yourRpcHandler : virtual public service_rpcIf
{
public:
    yourRpcHandler() :
    {
        // Your initialization goes here
    }

    void SomeMethod()
    {
        auto context = threadContextMap[std::this_thread::get_id()];

        // TODO: use the context as you see fit
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int port = 9090;
    printf("Listening on port %d\n", port);

    auto rpcHandler = new yourRpcHandler();
    shared_ptr<yourRpcHandler> handler(rpcHandler);
    shared_ptr<TProcessor> processor(new yourRpcProcessor(handler));
    shared_ptr<TServerTransport> serverTransport(new TServerSocket(port));
    shared_ptr<TTransportFactory> transportFactory(new TBufferedTransportFactory());
    shared_ptr<TProtocolFactory> protocolFactory(new TBinaryProtocolFactory());

    TThreadedServer server(processor, serverTransport, transportFactory, protocolFactory);
    shared_ptr<OurEventHandler> EventHandler(new OurEventHandler());

    server.setServerEventHandler(EventHandler);
    server.serve();
    return 0;
}
```